# Error when running tests in gradle automation project: Could not get unknown property 'testRuntime' for configuration ':cucumberRuntime'

Tags: java, automation

I am trying to run some automation code, but whenever I try to run it from the terminal (gradle runFeatures) I get the following error:

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   Could not get unknown property 'testRuntime' for configuration ':cucumberRuntime' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.

The error seems to emerge from two files: build.gradle and reRunReport.gradle

Both of them have the same line of code:

```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}
```

Do you know why this error appears?